# best way to manage failable init in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, initialization

I would have you opinion on the best way to manage failable initializers with swift.

My context : I have an SQLite local database and I would have an init for my object that returns me the object or nil if it doesn't exists on database.

So I went with failable initializer like this :

```
class A:ParentClass {
    var propertyA:String
    var propertyB:String
    ...

   init?(anId:String) {
        super.init()
        //try to load my object from database
        if let obj = CurrentContext.MySQLiteDBB().LoadA(anId){
            //id is in ParentClass
            self.id = obj.id
            self.propertyA = obj.propertyA
            self.propertyB = obj.propertyB
            self.propertyC = obj.propertyC
        }else{
            //the object not exists on DBB ...
            return nil
        }
}
```

This is doing the job but I don't like to have to assign all my property a second time (because I'm also creating a A object in the method LoadA()) ...

the best would be to have

```
return CurrentContext.MySQLiteDBB().LoadA(anId)
```

but it's not allowed in init (for good reasons) and I would like to avoid to use class function for that.

so, what do you think about this method ? I think I'm not the only one to have a local database with same problem to resolve :)

thank you,